# Prestashop modules development rich documentation

Tags: module, prestashop

Prestashop official documentation on modules development is basic. Do you know any other documentation that goes deeper on the module development?

Comment: you have read? https://validator.prestashop.com

Comment: Module development using Prestashop is quite a struggle, you have to search high and low on the Internet to find answers (which are mostly outdated), and delve into the Core files to know what is going on.

Comment: I'd recommend [Fabien Serny's PrestaShop Module Development](https://www.amazon.com/PrestaShop-Module-Development-Fabien-Serny/dp/1783280255) book which covers from basics to more advanced stuff such as payment and carrier module development, modules security etc. I somewhat agree with @JulienLachal it can be difficult at start to understand the core, specially with some class methods which are miles long but once you get the general idea of how the core works its much easier.